# Why is JsonHttpContent's output empty?

Tags: java, json, jackson, google-http-client

I am using Google Http Client library (1.20) on Google App Engine (1.9.30) to submit a POST request to Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) servers. Here's the code:

```
public static HttpRequestFactory getGcmRequestFactory() {
    if (null == gcmFactory) {
        gcmFactory = (new UrlFetchTransport())
                .createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                        request.getHeaders().setAuthorization(
                                "key=" + Config.get(Config.Keys.GCM_SERVER_API_KEY).orNull());
                        request.getHeaders().setContentType("application/json");
                        request.getHeaders().setAcceptEncoding(null);
                    }
                });
    }
    return gcmFactory;
}

public static JsonFactory getJsonFactory() {
    return jacksonFactory;
}

public static String sendGcmMessage(GcmDownstreamDto message) {
    HttpRequestFactory factory = getGcmRequestFactory();
    JsonHttpContent content = new JsonHttpContent(getJsonFactory(), message);
    String response = EMPTY;
    try {
        HttpRequest req = factory.buildPostRequest(gcmDownstreamUrl, content);
        log.info("req headers = " + req.getHeaders());
        System.out.print("req content = ");
        content.writeTo(System.out); // prints out "{}"
        System.out.println(EMPTY);
        HttpResponse res = req.execute(); // IOException here
        response = IOUtils.toString(res.getContent());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "IOException...", e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Now the `content.writeTo()` always prints out empty JSON. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? The `GcmDownstreamDto` class (using Lombok to generate getters and setters):

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class GcmDownstreamDto {

    private String to;

    private Object data;

    private List<String> registration_ids;

    private GcmNotificationDto notification;

    public GcmDownstreamDto addRegistrationId(String regId) {
        if (null == this.registration_ids) {
            this.registration_ids = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (isNotBlank(regId)) {
            this.registration_ids.add(regId);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

The immediate goal is to generate the same response as (from [Checking the validity of an API key](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#checkAPIkey)):

```
api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
       -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"

{"multicast_id":6782339717028231855,"success":0,"failure":1,
"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

I've already tested using `curl` so I know the API key is valid, I just want to do the same thing in Java code to build up my base classes.

`sendGcmMessage()` is being invoked as follows:

```
@Test
public void testGcmDownstreamMessage() {
    GcmDownstreamDto message = new GcmDownstreamDto().addRegistrationId("ABC");
    System.out.println("message = " + message);
    String response = NetCall.sendGcmMessage(message);
    System.out.println("Response: " + response);
}
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the problem: it's the way `JacksonFactory().createJsonGenerator().searialize()` works (I was expecting it to serialize the way `ObjectMapper` serializes). This is the code for `JsonHttpContent.writeTo()` (from [JsonHttpContent.java in google-http-java-client](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/782796/)):

```
public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    JsonGenerator generator = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(out, getCharset());
    generator.serialize(data);
    generator.flush();
}
```

The Jackson `JsonGenerator` expects a key-value pairing (represented in Java as `Map`) which is not obvious from the constructor signature of the `JsonHttpContent` constructor: `JsonHttpContent(JsonFactory, Object)`.

So if instead of passing a `GcmDownstreamDto` (as defined in the question, which is what would have worked with an `ObjectMapper`), I were to do the following:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> idList = Arrays.asList("ABC");
map.put("registration_ids", idList);
```

everything works as expected and the output is:

```
{"registration_ids":["ABC"]}
```

So just remember to pass the `JsonHttpContent(JsonFactory, Object)` constructor a `Map<String, Object>` as the second parameter, and everything will work as you would expect it to.

Answer (score 4):

You need to annotate the POJO fields with `@Key`:

```
import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

// ...

@Key private String to;
@Key private Object data;
@Key private List<String> registration_ids;

// ...
```